# Access the output of a layer defined within tf.keras.layers.Layer subclassing

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras, keras-layer

I want to access the output of one of the Linear layers defined within the MLPBlock class (code given below). So, how can I do that?

```
import tensorflow as tf
class Linear(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, units=32):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        self.units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(
            shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
            initializer="random_normal",
            trainable=True,
        )
        self.b = self.add_weight(
            shape=(self.units,), initializer="random_normal", trainable=True
        )

    def call(self, inputs):

        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.w) + self.b

class MLPBlock(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MLPBlock, self).__init__()
        self.linear_1 = Linear(32)
        self.linear_2 = Linear(32)
        self.linear_3 = Linear(1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        x = self.linear_1(inputs)
        x = tf.nn.relu(x)
        x = self.linear_2(x)
            x = tf.nn.relu(x)
            return self.linear_3(x)
    
mlp = MLPBlock()
```

Note that I want to access the Linear layer output from an MLPBlock instance.
Is there any way I can access those layers' output, like accessing the output of any intermediate layer of tf.keras.Model instance with '.get_layer' and '.output' methods.

Comment: When you pass `self.linear_1(inputs)`, you get the outpout of that layer.